# How to create a dictionary dynamically based on number of attributes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, k-means

I have a CSV file with 6 attributes and 1 class which I read with Pandas.

```
CsvFile = "/path/to/file.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(CsvFile)
```

First 5 rows of my CSV:

```
x,y,x1,y1,x2,y2,class
92,115,120,94,84,102,3
84,102,106,79,84,102,3
84,102,102,83,80,102,3
80,102,102,79,84,94,3
84,94,102,79,80,94,3
```

Since I have 6 attributes, I want to create a dictionary in Python (6 keys, 5 values each key) which will have the centroids for kmeans.

```
numberOfClusters = 5
centroids =
{
    i+1: [random.uniform(0.0, 255.0), random.uniform(0.0, 255.0),
          random.uniform(0.0, 255.0), random.uniform(0.0, 255.0),
          random.uniform(0.0, 255.0), random.uniform(0.0, 255.0)]
    for i in range(numberOfClusters)
}
```

**Question nr.1:** as you understand, it's not very productive to copy-paste the `random.uniform(0.0, 255.0)` as many times as the random points I want to get in order to match the number of attributes in my CSV file. Any idea how to do that without copy-paste?

In a similar fashion, in the following code I calculate the Euclidean distance.

```
for i in centroids.keys():
    df['distance_from_{}'.format(i)] = (
        np.sqrt(
            (df['x'] - centroids[i][0]) ** 2
            + (df['y'] - centroids[i][1]) ** 2
            + (df['x.1'] - centroids[i][2]) ** 2
            + (df['y.1'] - centroids[i][3]) ** 2
            + (df['x.2'] - centroids[i][4]) ** 2
            + (df['y.2'] - centroids[i][5]) ** 2
        )
    )
```

**Question nr.2:** if I have more attributes I have to add more `df['x'] - centroids[i][0]) ** 2`, whereas delete one or more if I have less. How can I automate this process a bit?

The reason for not using scikit's kmeans is that I want to calculate weights per cluster.

Comment: Rather than "`(6 keys, 5 values each key)"` did you mean `"(5 keys, 6 values each key)"`?  If so you can use `[random.uniform(0.0, 255.0) for _ in range(number_values)]` for creating list of values, where number_values is the number of values rather than copy/pasting.

Answer (score 1):

If  number of keys is the problem you can use

```
n=0
with open('filename.csv','r') as f:
    l=f.readline().strip()
    n=len(l.split(','))
```

where n holds number of keys

Answer (score 1):

First question: replace your list by

```
[random.uniform(0.0, 255.0) for x in range(6)]
```

Second question:

```
np.sqrt(np.sum(np.pow(df[df.columns[:5]] - centroid[i], 2)) should work.
```

Comment: Suggestion for 1st question doesn't work, it doesn't create a dict but a list instead.
It is ok although for the 2nd question.